# Як правильно перекласти true і false в значенні як терміни в програмуванні?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Перекладаю сайт з програмування комп'ютерної графіки.
Виникло таке питання.
В програмуванні часто функція повертає булеве значення **true** або **false**.

Як правильно перекласти ці слова?
Може вони в літературі використовуються без перекладу?

Comment: Я прибрав теґ "програмування", тому що, швидше за все, у нас не буде теґів з тематичних галузей.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

«Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» Є. Мейнаровича та М. Кратка (2010) пропонує серед інших такі переклади:

> [true](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=true&dicts=2&main_only=on) = 1. і́стина, пра́вда <…> 2. реа́льність
>   [false(hood)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=false&dicts=2&main_only=on) = 1. хи́бність, помилко́вість 2. хи́ба

Українська Вікіпедія в статтях про команди Unix [true](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_(Unix)) та [false](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(Unix)):

> логічне значення «істина»
>   логічне значення «хибність»

В локалізаціях програмних продуктів Microsoft ці терміни або не перекладаються, або перекладаються таким чином:

> істина //[Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, інші](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=true&langID=uk-ua)
>   хибність //[Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10, Exchange Client 2016, інші](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=false&langID=uk-ua)

Складається враження, що спроби перекласти як «**істина**» і «**хибність**» поширені — хоча не факт, що найправильніші.

---

Хоча є й інші варіанти, наприклад та ж українська Вікіпедія в інших статтях:

- [стаття «Логічний тип даних»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85): «називаються *істиною* і *хибою* (також *так* й *ні*)»;
- [стаття «Таблиці істинності»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%96_%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96): «істина», «хиба»;
- [стаття «Заперечення», розділ «Визначення»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F#.D0.92.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F): «правда», «неправда».

Answer (score 8):

Істина і хиба - усталені варіанти.

> Протилежністю істини (істинності) є хиба (хибність).

У варіанта істина/хибність немає шансів на виживання, просто тому, що хибність довше та й не римується.

**Google**:

1. [істина хиба логіка](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.12110j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - 308 000
2. [істина хибність логіка](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.12110j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0) - 33 400

Comment: Хиба - це також синонім до слів помилка, вада. Тому хибність точніша.

Comment: @АндрійБандура це може й правильно з точки зору точності, але дійсність каже, що люди частіше використовують хиба. Це лише про переклад *false*

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю як зараз, але під час мого навчання на факультеті кібернетики (початок 90-х) усталеними термінами у викладачів було "істина"/"фальш" (відп., "істинне/фальшиве твердження").

Answer (score 0):

true - не тільки "правдивий", але й "дійсний" також, якщо послуговуватися прикметниками.